# CSV columns visually divided in the separators to equal spaces like tabstops with CSV.vim?

Tags: insert-mode, visual-mode, formatting

When you open a CSV file with the [CSV.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) plugin the separators, such as semicolons, do not visually divide the columns in a format like the screenshot below. How can I visually separate the columns like tabstop with CSV.vim plugin?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question but maybe [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) is what you are looking for? I allows you to automatically add enough spaces between separators to align them vertically.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:ArrangeColumn` for that.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/blob/b64fb6895f90721fedb861d56ebcbbb70d80069e/doc/ft-csv.txt#L207) :

```
If you would like all columns to be visually arranged, you can use the 
`:ArrangeColumn` or `:CSVArrangeColumn` command.
```

e.g.:

Before:

[image]

Result:

[image]